# How to draw or make a calendar?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface

I am trying to make/draw a calendar. I am currently using canvas to draw it but I was wondering if anyone knew of a better way? I just want to display a month view of a calendar. I have .ics files on an SD card. The only difficulty I am having is how to draw the actual calendar. I also am trying to to make it so when the user clicks on a day a dialog pops up telling the user what events they have scheduled for that day. Any tips? I am looking at GridView as an alternative to drawing it using Canvas and Paint.

Thanks,
-G

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to make something yourself, you could use this open source android calendar, which seems to have a month view function (as you requested):

http://bit.ly/b0IDSe

Even though this calendar probably doesn't have the functionality that you described in your this to last sentence, it probably wouldn't be too much work to implement it into the existing code.

Comment: the link refer to "Downloading the Source Tree" of android